# Accessing the file from a form with a input file element

Tags: javascript, file, html, file-upload

I want to access a file(e.g. image) using JavaScript with such a form:

```
<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" size="40" value="" id="upload" name="upload"/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Is there a way to do it? I am trying to load a image specified by the client into a html5 cavas element without sending it back to the server.

Comment: Without using a browser plugin (Flash, or Java applet), you can do this with the HTML5 JS File API, but this feature is only available in FF 3.6+, Safari 6+, Chrome 7+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/
> - http://thinkvitamin.com/code/how-to-draw-with-html-5-canvas/
> - http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2009/02/html5-canvas-cheat-sheet.html

hope this help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The first link is what I needed.

Comment: Can I ask how you solved this? I'm trying to solve the same problem ([wrapping dropzonejs as Ember component](https://ember-cli-dropzonejs.firebaseapp.com))